# Automate Excel to fetch data from web url

Tags: excel, url, vba

*For example lets take imdb(movie rating) website* -I have an excel sheet with 10K movie name in column A

I copy a name from sheet-
Search it in url (http://www.imdb.com/) in search box.-
Copy the result(rating / actors) & paste in the sheet at column B,C,D

Is there a way I can automate this process.

Note:the URL I have to use requires login id/password.

Answer (score 3):

Excel can connect to web pages to get data. This can be utilized in your code with VBA, external .qry file, or using the 'get external data' interface. Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa203721(v=office.11).aspx