# excel macro to search a website and extract results

Tags: excel, extract, html, vba

I have a value in Sheet 1, A1.  It is either a business name, or its associated business number (as the site searches by number or name). Once I have entered the business name (or number) of the business I need the details on, I want to be able to click a "search" button and have the results of  the search displayed in a table with 2 columns (say sheet 1, A5:B9) with the labels in left column of table and the results in the right.
the site i need to search is http://www.abr.business.gov.au/
eg. If i search for the business number 31701562618 these are the results i get (and how i need displayed in excel:

```
      Column A                       Column B
5   Entity name:                  AMBROSE, BENJAMIN STEPHEN
6   ABN status:                   Active from 05 Apr 2000
7   Entity type:                  Individual/Sole Trader
8   Goods & Services Tax (GST):   Registered from 01 Jul 2000
9   Main business location:       QLD 4310
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automate Excel to fetch data from web url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576542/automate-excel-to-fetch-data-from-web-url)

Comment: Thanks. Like said i have seen a lot like this however I have not been successful in amending code. I dont claim to be a programmer - If I was I would not be asking the question in the first place - although i would be providing the help to those that ask.  This is the first time I have ever used a forum for HELP as I know the basics of code - and been able to amend other code I used for other projects yet this task is one (despite a lot of effort) I am unable to.    If you cannot help then dont bother replying - just move onto the next post as it adds no value to those seeking help.

Answer (score 3):

After some more tinkering i managed to get this to work. This just searches the site for the value in A1, grabs the results data and puts it into cell  starting at A5. NO formatting however that is easy enough to include after the 'End With' bit.

```
Sub URL_Get_ABN_Query()
strSearch = Range("a1")
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://www.abr.business.gov.au/SearchByABN.aspx?SearchText=" & strSearch & "&safe=active", _
Destination:=Range("a5"))

.BackgroundQuery = True
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With
End Sub
```