# Excel macro to search a website with excel data and extract specific results and then loop for next value for another webiste

Tags: excel, vba

I have replicated the code in [Excel macro to search a website with excel data and extract specific results and then loop for next value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263918/excel-macro-to-search-a-website-with-excel-data-and-extract-specific-results-and), although I get a error on the line URL_Get_SKU_Query1 = entityRange.Offset(0, 1).Value2 stating "object variable or with block variable not set"

So I am just trying to replicate the code for another website.
This code pulls in a certain text and spits out a value from the webiste.

So I would like to enter in MFR SKU in sheet 1 as such:

Name // SKU // Price
WaterSaverFaucet // SS902BC

After I have created a macro button on sheet 2 and clicking it

Then have it spit out the price.

So that it ends up like this below:

Name // SKU // Price
WaterSaverFaucet // SS902BC // 979.08

I would need this in order to look up multiple items on a website.

```
Sub LoopThroughBusinesses1()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SKU As String
    For i = 2 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        SKU = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = URL_Get_SKU_Query1(SKU)
    Next i
End Sub

Function URL_Get_SKU_Query1(strSearch As String) As String ' Change it from a Sub to a Function that returns the desired string
    ' strSearch = Range("a1") ' This is now passed as a parameter into the Function
    Dim entityRange As Range
    With Sheet2.QueryTables.Add( _
         Connection:="URL;https://www.neobits.com/SearchBySKU.aspx?SearchText=" & strSearch & "&safe=active", _
         Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1"))        ' Change this destination to Sheet2

        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With

    ' Find the Range that has "Price"
    Set entityRange = Sheet2.UsedRange.Find("Price")

    ' Then return the value of the cell to its' right
    URL_Get_SKU_Query1 = entityRange.Offset(0, 1).Value2

    ' Clear Sheet2 for the next run
    Sheet2.UsedRange.Delete

End Function
```

Comment: perhaps provide us a with a full working url and expected result?

Comment: Please check my edit to your post to see if it accurately represents your intended full code post. Then see if you can reduce the amount of code to just that which is required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Hello thank you for the input, I have changed the link so that it would direct you to where I originally found the code. I have tested the code from the link and it is working properly and provided more information as to what I would like the code to do.

Comment: You cannot simply assume you can transfer the logic. You need valid urls. For me, at least, the construct https://www.neobits.com/SearchBySKU.aspx?SearchText=SS902BC&safe=active    yeilds 404 page not found. Unless,  I have missed something (entirely possible) the reason for your error is an invalid url meaning your later selectors won't be found.

Comment: From the example that I used URL;http://www.abr.business.gov.au/SearchByABN.aspx?SearchText= has worked properly, although I am not sure what "SearchByABN.aspx?SearchText= meant, is there a reasoning behind this coding? If you would you be able to help me modify my URL so that it is working properly I would appreciate it. For example I would like the price from this URL https://www.neobits.com/watersaver_faucet_ss902bc_ss902bc_p9597758.html when entering into excel and executing the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is flawed unfortunately. You cannot simply take the mechanism from one webpage and assume it works for the next. In this case the solution you are trying will not work. When you enter a SKU into search what actually happens is a page re-direct (302). Not the construction of an url as you have tried. You are getting the error you see primarily due to hitting a page not found - though surfaces due to your element not being found on the 404 page.

Instead, you can use the construct the page in question actually uses for initial url and then you can use xmlhttp which will follow the re-direct as follows:

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetPrices()
    Dim xhr As XMLHTTP60, html As HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set xhr = New XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    Dim allData()
    allData = ws.UsedRange.Value

    With xhr
        For i = 2 To UBound(allData, 1)
            .Open "GET", "https://www.neobits.com/search?keywords=" & allData(i, 2), False
            .send
            Dim price As Object
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            Set price = html.querySelector("#main_price")
            If Not price Is Nothing Then
                allData(i, 3) = price.innerText
            Else
                allData(i, 3) = "No price found"
            End If
            Set price = Nothing
        Next
    End With
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(allData, 1), UBound(allData, 2)) = allData
End Sub
```

---

I assume your page set-up, in Sheet1, is as follows:

[image]

---

**Required project references:**

[image]

The two references bounded in red are required. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBE and then go `Tools > References` and add references. You may have a different version number for xml library - in which case reference will need changing as will code references of

```
Dim xhr As XMLHTTP60
```

and

```
New XMLHTTP60
```

---

**To run this code:**

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBE > Right click in project explorer > Add standard module. Paste code into that standard module > Select anywhere inside the code and press <kbd>F5</kbd>, or hit the green `Run` arrow in the ribbon.

---

**You could further develop, for example, to handle non 200 status codes:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetPrices()
    Dim xhr As XMLHTTP60, html As HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set xhr = New XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    Dim allData(), price As Object
    allData = ws.UsedRange.Value

    With xhr
        For i = 2 To UBound(allData, 1)
            .Open "GET", "https://www.neobits.com/search?keywords=" & allData(i, 2), False
            .send
                If .Status <> 200 Then
                    allData(i, 3) = "Status not succeeded" '<== Little bit loose but you get the idea.
                Else
                    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                    Set price = html.querySelector("#main_price")
                    If Not price Is Nothing Then
                        allData(i, 3) = price.innerText
                    Else
                        allData(i, 3) = "No price found"
                    End If
                Set price = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End With
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(allData, 1), UBound(allData, 2)) = allData
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for this robust answer. I am new to this community and this is my first question, I can see that this is a great community to ask questions and learn from. I will be taking this knowledge to any future projects. Thank you for being such a great teacher it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ' Find the Range that has "Entity Type:"
> Set entityRange = Sheet2.UsedRange.Find("Lists At:")
>
> ' Then return the value of the cell to its' right
> URL_Get_SKU_Query1 = entityRange.Offset(0, 1).Value2
> ```

The problem is that `Range.Find` may not find what you're looking for, for various reasons. [Always specify the optional parameters to that function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find#remarks), since it otherwise "conveniently remembers" the values from the last time it was invoked - either from other VBA code, or through the Excel UI (IOW there's no way to be 100% sure of what values it's going to be running with if you don't specify them). But even then, if `Range.Find` doesn't find what it's looking for, it will return `Nothing` - and you can't just assume that will never happen!

But, reading closer...

> ```
> ' Find the Range that has "Entity Type:"
> Set entityRange = Sheet2.UsedRange.Find("Lists At:")
> ```

Someone's lying. Read the comment. Now read the code. Who's telling the truth? Don't write comments that say "what" - have comments say "why", and let the code say "what". Otherwise you have situations like that, where it's impossible to tell whether the comment is outdated or the code isn't right, at least not without looking at the worksheet.

In any case, you need to make sure `entityRange` isn't `Nothing` before you try to make a member call against it:

```
If Not entityRange Is Nothing Then
    URL_Get_SKU_Query1 = entityRange.Offset(0, 1).Value2
End If
```