# Error 91 VBscript parsing html text to excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, html-parsing

I tried to simulate a VB Script from this forum:
[Search a website with Excel data to extract results and then loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263918/search-a-website-with-excel-data-to-extract-results-and-then-loop/54264223#54264223)

I got an error on this line:

```
URL_Get_ABN_Query = entityRange.Offset(0, 1).Value2
```

the error is:
error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Here is the two-part script of the said forum:

```
Sub LoopThroughBusinesses()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ABN As String
    For i = 2 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        ABN = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = URL_Get_ABN_Query(ABN)
    Next i
End Sub

Function URL_Get_ABN_Query(strSearch As String) As String   ' Change it from a Sub to a Function that returns the desired string
' strSearch = Range("a1") ' This is now passed as a parameter into the Function
Dim entityRange As Range
With Sheet2.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="URL;http://www.abr.business.gov.au/SearchByABN.aspx?SearchText=" & strSearch & "&safe=active", _
        Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1"))   ' Change this destination to Sheet2

    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With

' Find the Range that has "Finish"
Set entityRange = Sheet2.UsedRange.Find("Entity type:")

' Then return the value of the cell to its' right
URL_Get_ABN_Query = entityRange.Offset(0, 1).Value2

' Clear Sheet2 for the next run
Sheet2.UsedRange.Delete

End Function
```

Comment: Looks like your Find() did not make a match.

Comment: When using `find()` you should always test to see if there was a match - in this case `If Not entityRange Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the comment. When I debug it always highlight to this part

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the comment. When I debug it always highlight to this part (line 29):

URL_Get_ABN_Query = entityRange.Offset(0, 1).Value2

Comment: Please *update your question* and add your code there.  Code in comments is not easy to read.

Comment: can you show me the complete script about If Not entityRange Is Nothing Then fix?

Answer (score 0):

Following from comments above:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Debug.Print URL_Get_ABN_Query("44627939854") '>> Discretionary Trading Trust
    Debug.Print URL_Get_ABN_Query("XXXX")        '>> Not found
    
End Sub

Function URL_Get_ABN_Query(strSearch As String) As String
    
    Dim entityRange As Range
    With Sheet2.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="URL;http://www.abr.business.gov.au/SearchByABN.aspx?SearchText=" & strSearch & "&safe=active", _
        Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1"))

        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With

    'when using Find, you should always specify at least the `lookat` argument...
    '  xlPart (matches part) or xlWhole (full match)
    Set entityRange = Sheet2.UsedRange.Find(what:="Entity type:", lookat:=xlPart)
    
    'check to see if a match was made by Find()
    If Not entityRange Is Nothing Then
        URL_Get_ABN_Query = entityRange.Offset(0, 1).Value2
    Else
        URL_Get_ABN_Query = "Not found"
    End If
    Sheet2.UsedRange.Delete ' Clear Sheet2 for the next run

End Function
```

Comment: Still I got blank results even I replaced your first half with the original from mine.

Comment: The code as posted works fine for me - did you try it as-is?

Comment: Yes. What results did you get? I got blank or null in Sheet2

Comment: I got the text shown in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G in the VB editor if that's not open for you).  There's nothing in sheet 2 because the last line in `URL_Get_ABN_Query` is `Sheet2.UsedRange.Delete`

Comment: Here is the result:

Discretionary Trading Trust
Not found
Discretionary Trading Trust
Not found.

I need to automate my parsing somehow. I like to put the results in Sheet2 from over a thousand rows.

My real target is to parse finish type from this 

https://www.hardwareresources.com/307fu.html?item_overall_length=

with sample item number below:

209FU20
209FU22
209FU24

so for example if you try:

https://www.hardwareresources.com/307fu.html?item_overall_length=209FU20

you will learn it is a clear zinc finish

I appreciate your kind help. Thanks.