# How to search a website using a range of cells in excel to extract specific data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search the website "capfriendly.com/players/" using a column of cells and import the "Cap Hit" value back into excel in the adjacent column for each.

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to programming, so I've mostly been trying to learn from previous questions such as this one: [excel macro to search a website and extract results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682639/excel-macro-to-search-a-website-and-extract-results)

I'm still pretty perplexed, especially with how to extract just the specific value I'm looking for. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Please remember to include your code using [edit] (whatever you have written) so we can reproduce the problem you are having and tailor our solutions accordingly. Make it clear what the code should be doing and what it is actually doing.

Comment: Where is the code you are using and what problems are you having with it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of Excel you work with.

Anyway you can try this :

Create a new sheet.

Go to Data in the ribbon to get external data and choose "From web".

Input the url of your page ie https://www.capfriendly.com/browse
After a moment you should retrieve "Results" data that you can load with or without structure modifications. You now have a data table in your new sheet.

You can now access it with Vlookup or similar function, with VBA code or with formulas, to put specific data on specific cells of specific sheets like you need to.

Hope it helps.